# Close file download window popup in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, popup

I have some computers with Internet Explorer 7 and 8. They continuously receive files from server through Internet Explorer. Sometimes, the download file popup doesn't close automatically, and I have to do that manually. I have a lot of computers so I can't manage this manually.

Is it possible close this window executing a visual script file to close it? Or there is another simpler method?

Photo:

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/do9w68.jpg]

Comment: Do you always get the file from the one page, on which you're planning to place your javascript code?

Comment: I get the file in every computer. I want to execute the javascript file in each computer where the file is downloaded, to close the popup

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to do so with javascript, since it can close only windows it opened - in other words, the window must be opened in js in order to be able to be closed from js. I would consider however installing download manager wich has more configuration options, and will operate in single window only.For instance you can try [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/). It's open source and free to use.

Comment: I can't install third party software on my computers. Can it be done with vbscript? I use `iexplore.exe -k http://myserver.php` to open in full screen. Thank you.